# What are the date formats available in SimpleDateFormat class?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Can anybody let me know about the date formats available in SimpleDateFormat class.

I have gone through api but could not find a satisfactory answer.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What format are you after?  You have to _build_ a format comprised of the elements you need.

Comment: You can construct any format the API allows. There is no definitive list.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Date and time formats are well described below

[SimpleDateFormat (Java Platform SE 7) - Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

There could be `n` Number of formats you can possibly make. ex - `dd/MM/yyyy` or `YYYY-'W'ww-u` or you can mix and match the letters to achieve your required pattern. Pattern letters are as follow.

- `G` - Era designator (AD)
- `y` - Year   (1996; 96)
- `Y` - Week   Year (2009; 09)
- `M` - Month in year (July; Jul; 07)
- `w` - Week in year (27)
- `W` - Week in month (2)
- `D` - Day in year    (189)
- `d` - Day in month (10)
- `F` - Day of week in month (2)
- `E` - Day name in week (Tuesday; Tue)
- `u` - Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)
- `a` - AM/PM marker
- `H` - Hour in day (0-23)
- `k` - Hour in day (1-24)
- `K` - Hour in am/pm (0-11)
- `h` - Hour in am/pm (1-12)
- `m` - Minute in hour (30)
- `s` - Second in minute (55)
- `S` - Millisecond    (978)
- `z` - General time zone (Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00)
- `Z` - RFC 822 time zone (-0800)
- `X` - ISO 8601 time zone (-08; -0800; -08:00)

To parse:

> 2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+0000

Use:
`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");`

Comment: Thanks Quoi..But could you please let me know how may I convert dates into different standards like EST,IST,gdt,gmt etc?

Comment: Then you are looking for date in different locale. `SimpleDateFormat` allow to set locale at constructor. `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale);`

Comment: Don't confuse Z and 'Z'. I was fool and I hope anybody else won't be like me.

Comment: @TiefanJu it looks like `z` accepts "Z" :)

Answer (score 55):

Let me throw out some example code that I got from http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DateTimeCalendar.html  Then you can play around with different options until you understand it.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Date now = new Date();

       //This is just Date's toString method and doesn't involve SimpleDateFormat
       System.out.println("toString(): " + now);  // dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
       //Shows  "Mon Oct 08 08:17:06 EDT 2012"

       SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, y-M-d 'at' h:m:s a z");
       System.out.println("Format 1:   " + dateFormatter.format(now));
       // Shows  "Mon, 2012-10-8 at 8:17:6 AM EDT"

       dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
       System.out.println("Format 2:   " + dateFormatter.format(now));
       // Shows  "Mon 2012.10.08 at 08:17:06 AM EDT"

       dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");
       System.out.println("Format 3:   " + dateFormatter.format(now));
       // Shows  "Monday, October 8, 2012"

       // SimpleDateFormat can be used to control the date/time display format:
       //   E (day of week): 3E or fewer (in text xxx), >3E (in full text)
       //   M (month): M (in number), MM (in number with leading zero)
       //              3M: (in text xxx), >3M: (in full text full)
       //   h (hour): h, hh (with leading zero)
       //   m (minute)
       //   s (second)
       //   a (AM/PM)
       //   H (hour in 0 to 23)
       //   z (time zone)
       //  (there may be more listed under the API - I didn't check)

   }
```

}

Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

## java.time

**UPDATE**

The other Questions are outmoded. The terrible legacy classes such as `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

## Custom

For defining your own custom formatting patterns, the codes in [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) are similar to but not exactly the same as the codes in `SimpleDateFormat`. Be sure to study the documentation. And search Stack Overflow for many examples.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( 
        "dd MMM uuuu" , 
        Locale.ITALY 
    ) 
;
```

## Standard ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines formats for many types of date-time values. These formats are designed for data-exchange, being easily parsed by machine as well as easily read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default  when generating/parsing strings. Simply call the `toString` & `parse` methods. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2018-11-05T18:19:33.017554Z

For a value in UTC, the `Z` on the end means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

## Localize

Rather than specify a formatting pattern, you can let *java.time*  automatically localize for you. Use the `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.

Get current moment with the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

> zdt.toString(): 2018-11-05T19:20:23.765293+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

Generate auto-localized text.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale );

String output = zdt.format( f );
```

> output: lundi 5 novembre 2018 à 19:20:23 heure normale d’Europe centrale

Generally a better practice to auto-localize rather than fret with hard-coded formatting patterns.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 4):

check the formats here  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

**main**

```
System.out.println("date  : " + new classname().getMyDate("2014-01-09 14:06", "dd-MMM-yyyy E hh:mm a z", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```

**method**

```
 public String getMyDate(String myDate, String returnFormat, String myFormat)
            {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(returnFormat);
                Date date=null;
                String returnValue="";
                try {
                    date = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(myDate);
                    returnValue = dateFormat.format(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    returnValue= myDate;
                    System.out.println("failed");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return returnValue;
            }
```