# Custom the display value of SimpleDateFormat in android

Tags: android, date, datetime, formatting, string-formatting

I currently work on a double value that represent the total consumed time

for example, I have a 260 that means 260 second is consumed

To display to user, I would like to format it

for example , it should be something like 0year,0month,0day,1hr,2min,30sec

But I found the `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");` is not quite suit my case (seems the "h" in "hr" is conflicted with the hour symbol?)

So , how to change the HH:mm:ss to the case mentioned above?

Thanks for helping

Comment: chech this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781273/what-are-the-date-formats-available-in-simpledateformat-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateFormat is useful to format dates, not an absolute value of time.

To achieve your goal, you can take a look to [Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)

Hope this sample helps you:

```
String total_consumed_time = String.format("%01d year, %01d month, %01d day, %01d hr, %01d min, %01d sec", time_year, time_month, time_day, time_hour, time_min, time_seg);
```

I didn't try that code, but I use similar workaround with an absolute time in milliseconds:

```
long time = 260000; // time in mseg
long time_hour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(time);
time -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(time_hour);
long time_min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time);
time -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(time_min);
long time_seg = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(time);
String total_time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", time_hour, time_min, time_seg);
```

With a result of "00:04:20" (4 minutes and 20 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

**Accepted answer is in most cases okay for solving your problem, but gives wrong reason why not to use the class `SimpleDateFormat`.** This format class is well suited for objects of type `java.util.Date` (which are kind of unix timestamps in milliseconds hence absolute value of time, NOT dates). In order to treat letters like "hr" as literals you need to **escape** them. Example code:

```
// create timestamp
java.util.Date jud = new java.util.Date(260 * 1000); // milliseconds

// create format for timestamp
SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'year',M'month',d'day',H'hr',m'min',s'sec'");

// otherwise you will get extra offset time (example: in England +1 hour DST)
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

// output: 1970year,1month,1day,0hr,4min,20sec
String formatted = sdf.format(jud);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Even with the applied and tricky time zone correction in code you face the problem that you have an output for the year 1970, a point in time. Hereby you can see that `SimpleDateFormat` does **format timestamps** well (absolute values in time) but **NOT durations** (amount resp. length of time). This semantic problem can also not be solved by the approach to use `java.util.Formatter` as soon as the input increases the day limit of 86400 seconds.

Old JDK and Android don't offer a built-in solution for evaluating time differences expressed in years, months and days. Java 8 does offer (limited) support with [new API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) (class 'Period' only for date part, not time part). External libraries like [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period%28org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,%20org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,%20org.joda.time.PeriodType%29) or my own one (actually only as alpha-version) give more support. JodaTime even offers a special `PeriodFormatter` which is ideal for solving your problem.