# Java String to Date object of the format “MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a”

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, datetime-conversion

I need to convert a `String` containing a date into a date object.

The `String` will be in the format `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"` and I want the `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a "` format as result.

```
String dateString = "2018-03-20 09:31:31";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a", 
                                                           Locale.ENGLISH);

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString , formatter);
```

The code above is throwing an exception.

Comment: "I want the "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a "format in an date object." There's no such thing. A `LocalDate` value doesn't have a format. You can parse to a `LocalDate` (by providing the format of your input string when you parse) but then it's just a `LocalDate`. If you want a particular text representation later, you format the value with an appropriate formatter.

Comment: Your string pattern and your parser pattern don't match

Comment: LocalDate doesn't contain time info. So you have to use LocalDateTime instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use two `Formatter`, one to covert `String` to `LocalDateTime` and the other to format this date as you want :

**From String to LocalDateTime :**

```
String dateString = "2018-03-20 09:31:31";

LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(
        dateString,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
);
```

**Now From LocalDateTime to String :**

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH
);

String newDate = date.format(formatter);
System.out.println(newDate);// 03/20/2018 09:31:31 AM
```

---

**Note :** You have to use `LocalDateTime` instead of just `LocalDate`, your format contain both date and time, not just date, else you will get an error :

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: HourOfDay
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a common error, based on the misconception that dates have formats - but [they actually don't](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Date/time objects have only **values**, and those values - usually numerical - represent the concept of a date (a specific point in the calendar) and a time (a specific moment of the day).

If you have a `String`, then you don't actually have a date. You have a **text** (a sequence of characters) that represents a date. Note that all of the strings below are different (they have a different sequence of characters), but all represent the same date (the same values, the same point in the calendar):

- `2018-03-20 09:31:31`
- `03/20/2018 9:31:31 AM` (using USA's format: month/day/year)
- `Tuesday, March 20th 2018, 09:31:31 am`
- and many others...

What you want to do is to get one format (one `String`, one text representing a date) and transform it to another format (anoter `String`, another different sequence of characters that represents the same date).

In Java (and in many other languages - if not all - btw) you must do it in 2 steps:

1. convert the `String` to a date/time object (convert the text to the numerical values) - that's what the `parse` method does
2. convert the date/time object to another format (convert the numerical values to another text)

That said, when you call the `parse` method, you're trying to transform a `String` (a text, a sequence of characters) into a date/time object. This means that the `DateTimeFormatter` must have a pattern that matches the input.

The input is `2018-03-20 09:31:31`, which is `year-month-day hour:minute:second`. And the formatter you used to parse it has the pattern `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a` (`month/day/year hour:minute:second am/pm`).

You used the output pattern (the one that should be used in step 2) to parse the input. That's why you've got an exception: the formatter tried to parse a month with 2 digits followed by a `/` when the input actually contains a year with 4 digits followed by a `-`.

You must use a different `DateTimeFormatter` for each step, using the correct pattern for each case. YCF_L's answer has the code that does the job, I'd just like to add one little detail. The formatter used for the output (step 2) is:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH
);
```

Note that `HH` is used for the hours. [Take a look at the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) and you'll see that uppercase `HH` represents the **hour-of-day** fields (values from 0 to 23 - so 1 AM is printed as `01` and 1 PM is printed as `13`).

But you're also printing the AM/PM field (the `a` in the pattern), so maybe what you need is actually the lowercase `hh`, which is the **clock-hour-of-am-pm** (values from 1 to 12) or even `KK` (**hour-of-am-pm** (values from 0 to 11)).

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateString = "2018-03-20 09:31:31";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

try {
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String reportDate = df.format(date );
} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You  need to do a 2 steps conversion:

1. from your String date time in the *wrong format* to a (tempoary) LocalDateTime object.
2. if you still  want to only  extract the date (Year-Month-day) do a `LocalDateTime.toLocalDate()`
3. From this LocalDateTime object into the your String object in the *right format*

   ```
       String dateString = "2018-03-20 09:31:31";

       DateTimeFormatter formatterForWrongFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
               .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
               .appendLiteral(" ")
               .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
               .toFormatter();

       //1- from String(wrong format) into datetime object
       LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString , formatterForWrongFormat);

       // 1.1 extract date object (Optional)
       LocalDate myDate =  dateTime.toLocalDate();

       // 2- now from your  LocalDateTime to the String in the RIGHT format
       DateTimeFormatter formatterForRightFormat =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a",
               Locale.ENGLISH);

       System.out.println("right format: "+dateTime.format(formatterForRightFormat));
   ```

you can test this code [here](https://ideone.com/Yepgg0)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the SimpleDateFormatter which is easier to implement and permit you to change the format of your date easily.

More here : [What are the date formats available in SimpleDateFormat class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781273/what-are-the-date-formats-available-in-simpledateformat-class)

Hope this will help you !

Comment: How exactly is `SimpleDateFormat` easier than `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` and the new `java.time` APIs are *much* better than the old `SimpleDateFormatter`/`Date`/`Calendar` APIs. The fundamental problem would still remain: the OP is expecting to parse a value with the wrong format, and expecting the value to "know" its format. That would be just as problematic in the old APIs.

Comment: Oh ok for the DateTimeFormatter  it may be much better ! But (for me) the SimpleDateFormat is  easier to use and it will work. And yes in this case he has to use 2 formatter like YCF_L said, and make sure you have the same format in input...