# How to convert unix time format to day format month date yeear and time format in java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

My time format is coming 
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");`

```
2108-03-27T17:18:16.985+0530
```

input Date I have to convert it into other time format

```
Mar 27,2018 5:18 pm
```

is expected output can any please suggest me how to convert given time to other time format in `java` .

Comment: Take a look at the Date and Time Patterns on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Also take a look at the Date and Time API https://dzone.com/articles/deeper-look-java-8-date-and

Comment: You can choose other date format instead convert given time to other time format. Here u have examples of other time formats. Try this: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d,yyyy h:mm a");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Java 8, use the java.time API:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                .appendPattern("XX")
                .toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2108-03-27T17:18:16.985+0530", parser);

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd,yyyy h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formattedDate = fmt.format(odt); // Mar 27,2108 5:18 PM
```

`SimpleDateFormat` has [lots of problems](https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/), many of them solved by java.time API, and you should prefer to use those.

For older versions of Java, there's a [nice backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), with the same classes and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

//Mar 27, 2018 06:28 PM

for more
[What are the date formats available in SimpleDateFormat class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781273/what-are-the-date-formats-available-in-simpledateformat-class)

Comment: my input is 2108-03-27T17:18:16.985+0530  in this format how i will convert it in Date format @Roushan45

Answer (score 0):

You can convert type any-to-any of date format.

You just need to pass String format to `SimpleDateFormate`.

Use this method as `static` and call it from anywhere by passing `inputDate`

**Simplified Date convert method:**

```
public static String getFormattedDate(String inputDate)
{
    String outputFormattedDate = "";
    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z");
        Date inputFormatDate = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);

        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy h:mm a");
        outputFormattedDate = outputFormat.format(inputFormatDate);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        outputFormattedDate = inputDate;
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outputFormattedDate;
}
```

Hope it will help you.