# SQL timeStamp format is different on windows and ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, timestamp

I have a db in mysql in which one column is of `timstamp` datatype.
It stores timstamp in this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss`on both windows and linux.
But when i am fetching data from mysql from my java code, it brings data in this format `May 11, 2018, 11:35:34 AM` on my windows and in this format `May 11, 2018 11:35:34 AM` on `linux ubuntu`.

How make timestamp format consistent?

Comment: Just to confirm my suspicion: could it be that you're using JDK9 on Windows and 8 on Linux?

Comment: i am using JDK9 on my windows machine and JDK8 on my linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a change in behavior in JDK9, where the default formats being used are now those of Unicode CLDR, as explained here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#JSINT-GUID-9DCDB41C-A989-4220-8140-DBFB844A0FCA

The article explains one way of changing this behavior, by overriding the `java.locale.providers` property.

The solution I would prefer (as although more elaborate it also allows for more flexibility) is to always use an explicit formatter for date time values. Eg look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781273/what-are-the-date-formats-available-in-simpledateformat-class)