# Parse timestamp string to Java.sql.timestamp

Tags: java

I have the following timestamp in String format

```
2019-04-06T00:43:21+00:00
2019-04-04T21:24:33+00:00
2019-04-04T21:02:16+00:00
```

How can I parse the timestamp strings above to `Java.sql.timestamp`?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and confusing and long outdated. For use with an SQL database depending on the SQL datatype and your JDBC driver’s capabilities instead use either `Instant`, `OffsetDateTIme` or `LocalDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateFormat to parse your String.

```
 try{
     String x="2019-04-04T21:24:33+00:00";
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX");
     Date date = (Date) df.parse(x);
     java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
 }catch(ParseException pe){
     pe.printStackTrace();
 }
```

As mentioned by others in comments, there is a more updated way to do this.

```
String time="2019-04-04T21:02:16+00:00";
OffsetDateTime odt=OffsetDateTime.parse(time,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp=new java.sql.Timestamp(odt.toEpochSecond()*1000);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781273/what-are-the-date-formats-available-in-simpledateformat-class

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes as of the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting `Date`, `Timestamp`, and `SimpleDateFormat` in 2019 is poor advice.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Timestamp                                   // Avoid this terrible legacy class if possible. Represents a moment in UTC. 
.from(                                      // Convert from modern `Instant` to legacy `Timestamp`. No data loss, as both resolve to nanoseconds.
    OffsetDateTime                          // Modern way to represent a moment with an offset-from-UTC (hours, minutes, and seconds).
    .parse( "2019-04-06T00:43:21+00:00" )   // Parse standard ISO 8601 strings. Returns a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object.
    .toInstant()                            // Extract an `Instant` from the `OffsetDateTime`, thereby adjusting to UTC (an offset of zero). 
)                                           // Returns a `Timestamp` object, if needed to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*.
```

Even better, skip the terrible `Timestamp` class entirely.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(                           // As of JDBC 4.2 and later, exchange *java.time* objects with your database.
    1 ,                                                  // Specify the nth placeholder in your SQL statement. 
    OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-04-06T00:43:21+00:00" )  // Parse an ISO 8601 compliant string as a `OffsetDateTime` object, a moment with an offset-from-UTC. Pass to the database via the `setObject` call.
)
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your input strings indicate an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (a number of hours-minutes-seconds), that part at the end.

Your input strings are in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default in parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-04-06T00:43:21+00:00" ) ;
```

## <s>`java.sql.Timestamp`</s>

Never use `java.util.Timestamp`. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

If you must have a [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert by calling new methods added to the old classes. Extract a `Instant` from the `OffsetDateTime` (thereby adjusting from any offset to an offset of zero, for UTC itself). Pass the `Instant` object to [`Timestamp.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from(java.time.Instant)).

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from( odt.toInstant() ) ;
```

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. So search for more info. And in the future, search thoroughly before posting.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).